# How can I get the correct service based on an enum parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have an implementation like below. The code is only for explaining the problem, it is not real implementation. I have more than one data repositories and I want to have only one Data Service and I want to inject and consume that data service in my controllers but I don't like to have like that switch case in my implementation. Is there any better way or design for that? Or any suggestion?
Any better design is always welcome. Thanks in advance.

```
interface IDataService<T>
{
    Task<T> Get(RepoTypes repoType);
}

class DataService<T>:IDataService<T>
{
    private readonly IRepository<X> _xRepository;
     private readonly IRepository<Y> _yRepository;
    private readonly  IRepository<Z> _zRepository;
    private readonly  IMapper _mapper;

    public ClassName(IRepository<X> xRepository,
    IRepository<Y> yRepository,
    IRepository<Z> zRepository,
    IMapper mapper)
    {
        _xRepository = xRepository;
        _yRepository = yRepository;
        _zRepository = zRepository;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }
    public async Task<T>  GetTask(RepoTypes repoType)
    {
        switch (repoTypes)
        {
            case X:
                var data = await _xRepository.Get();
                return _mapper.Map<T>(data);
            case Y:
                var data = await _yRepository.Get();
                return _mapper.Map<T>(data);
            case Y:
                var data = await _zRepository.Get();
                return _mapper.Map<T>(data);
            default:
        }
    }
}

interface IRepository<T>
{
    Task<T> Get();
}
class IRepository<T>: IRepository<T>
{
    public async Task<T>  GetTask()
    {
        // some implementation
    }
}

public enum RepoTypes
{
    X,
    Y,
    Z
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its very hard to give you an answer without any specifics. Also, the example code isn't compilable and/or correct.

I also have a lot of questions regarding the architecture, without knowing that its really hard to provide a correct or satisfying answer.

Let me at least give a try as to perhaps help you get rid of the switch statement. A possible way of doing this is simply storing the values as key-value pairs and retrieving those values in the `Get(RepoTypes repoType)`, for example you could re-purpose the `DataService` class as follows:

```cs
public class DataService<T> : IDataService<T>
{
  private readonly IMapper _mapper;

  private Dictionary<RepoTypes, dynamic> _dict;

  public DataService(IRepository<ClassX> xRepository,
                     IRepository<ClassY> yRepository,
                     IRepository<ClassZ> zRepository,
                     IMapper mapper)
  {
    _mapper = mapper;

    _dict = new Dictionary<RepoTypes, dynamic>
    {
      { RepoTypes.X, xRepository },
      { RepoTypes.Y, yRepository },
      { RepoTypes.Z, zRepository }
    };
  }

  public async Task<T> Get(RepoTypes repoType)
  {
    var repo = _dict[repoType];
    var data = await repo.Get();
    return _mapper.Map<T>(data);
  }
}
```

Because of the type differences between the different `IRepository` interfaces, there's no other way of specifying the dictionary besides: `Dictionary<RepoTypes, dynamic>`.

Comment: thanks, that was only kind of  pseudocode, I was not also expecting to compile but I understood me correctly. Thanks for your help.